# How can I create *.xliff i18n file from PHP smarty scripts?

Tags: php, internationalization, smarty, translation, globalization

How can I create *.xliff i18n file from PHP smarty scripts?

I wan to extract *.po or *.xliff file from smarty scripts for example:

```
    {if !$sf_user->isAuthenticated()} 
    <a href="{url_for internal='stUser/loginUser' secure=true}" id="nav-button-user" class="btn btn-navbar collapsed" title="Zaloguj się">
        {__ text="Zaloguj się" langCatalogue="punkparrot"}<!-- <span id="login-status-info" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
        <small class="login-status">&nbsp;</small> -->
    </a> 
    {else}
    <button id="nav-button-user" class="btn btn-navbar collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-user" data-parent="#header-navbar" title="Twoje konto">
        {__ text="Moje konto" langCatalogue="punkparrot"}<!-- <span id="login-status-info" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
        <small class="login-status">&nbsp;</small> -->
    </button>            
    {/if}
```

How can I extract strings to translate from PHP smarty?